# Can I place and ad in a Container or a WebBrowser component in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

I am aware that Ad banners are supported in Codename One along with inneractive banners. But I would like to place an ad in a custom container such that it appears while scrolling down the container.  I am not sure if there is a way to place an add inside of a Container or a WebBrowser component at the moment.

This is the approach admob's native app had adopted: https://www.google.com/admob/monetize.html#?monetize-tabset_activeEl=native-ads

Answer (score 0):

We don't have builtin support for that but since you can place the browser component anywhere you want you can include web ads within that. They might not be ideal though.

Alternatively you can integrate a native banner ad framework and use peer component to place the UI view banner.

Comment: Why would you say including web ads may not be ideal ?  What would be the trade offs?
I just ran into the Facebook native ads. It would be nice if we could support it. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/native-ads
But they seem to also allow mobile web integration. This could be potentially a viable approach. 
https://www.facebook.com/audiencenetwork/native-ads/integrating-native-ads
I am not very familiar with PeerComponents.  Would you think PeerComponent or WebComponent would be more ideal for using Facebook ads. I will try to integrate FB ads this weekend.

Comment: Also ran into this one: http://www.mopub.com/resources/docs/ad-formats-best-practices/native-ads-best-practices/native-integration-overview/

Comment: Banner ads will probably be simpler to integrate than native ads. Most of our customers abandoned banners as the return on that is so low it's just unsustainable. Interstatials give better return and we do support them in a couple of cn1libs.